Top Bar disappeared in Ubuntu 24.04
I have a relatively new (i.e. less than a week old) installation of Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS, Noble Numbat (Ubuntu Pro enabled). Two days ago, I installed a few GNOME extensions using GNOME Shell - all but one of these extensions are simple customizations to the top bar (for example, I have a "Media Controls" extension installed, to view currently playing media). However, as I was browsing the internet, my top bar suddenly disappeared - instead I am left with a transparent view to my desktop where the top bar should be, as in the screenshot below.

This means that I am unable to see or use any of the functions in the top bar, including Quick Settings. I'm aware that I can restart my system via the Terminal, however I'd rather not do that as I have some work-in-progress to finish - and I prefer to keep my system running constantly without shutting down (for a few reasons, including that I have to re-set-up my network connection with each boot - which doesn't always work).
Weirdly, although my top bar appears blank, an extension I have installed named "Volume Scroller" still works (which increases or decreases the audio volume when you scroll up or down on the top bar) - so I can still adjust my volume by scrolling on the blank space where the top bar used to be.
How can I get my top bar back?

Note: This question is not a duplicate of Ubuntu 22.04.2 top bar disappearing, as I do not have a "hide top bar" extension or similar.

Full system details:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
CPU: Intel Core i7
RAM: 24GB (16GB + 8GB)
GPU: NVIDIA Geforce GTX 965M + Intel HD Integrated Graphics
Static hostname: Ubuntu
Icon name: computer-laptop
Chassis: laptop 
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-31-generic
Architecture: x86-64
Hardware Vendor: HP
Hardware Model: OMEN by HP Laptop
Firmware Version: F.09
Firmware Date: Tue 2016-07-19
Firmware Age: 8y 2month 2w 6d

Please note, I'm quite new to asking questions on this community. I hope my question is well-written; however if I've done something wrong, instead of downvoting right away, please consider leaving a comment and giving me a chance to edit my question first. Thanks =)

It would probably be useful to list which extensions you have installed. And maybe disable them one by one to see if the problem goes away.

It sounds like your (built in) gnome extension (top bar) has crashed. Following the above:  'gnome-extensions list' 'gnome-extensions disable {NameOfGnomeExtension}'  'gnome-extensions enable {NameOfGnomeExtension}' Then ironically you might like to install the gnome extension  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/  and turn of off-and-on again.
